# "catch her train", Why do we use "her"?

Tags: possessives, reflexive-pronouns

> Sarah got to the station just on time to catch **her** train to the airport.

Why do we use "her"? Does it mean Sarah already have the ticket in advance? if not, can we omit it?

Comment: In English, "possessive" forms (including the Saxon genitive **'s** as well as possessive pronouns) don't necessarily imply anything about "ownership". Your example is a perfectly natural usage that simply means the train ***associated*** with her in some way (in practice, usually just *the specific train she **intended** to catch*, whether booked and paid for or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that would make a good answer.

Comment: You could write "a train", but by saying "her train" makes it more specific, it is the correct train for her, perhaps she has to take a train at a specific time to arrive at the airport in time, or she already has a ticket.

Comment: People sometimes reflect that we use possessive pronouns as widely as: my shirt, my dog, my wife, my boss, my country and my God.

Comment: By the way, we usually say, just "in" time, not just "on" time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, "possessive" forms (including the Saxon genitive 's as well as possessive pronouns) don't necessarily imply anything about "ownership".

OP's example is a perfectly natural usage that simply means the train ***associated*** with her in some way (usually, just the specific train she ***intended*** to catch, whether booked and paid for or not).

---

Although it's not central to the question, I'd also like to address the point commented on by [@Teacher KSHuang](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120418/catch-her-train-why-do-we-use-her?noredirect=1#comment242915_120418) above *(we usually say **just "in" time**, not **just "on" time**).* I think [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arrived%20just%20on%20time%2Carrived%20just%20in%20time%2Carrived%20on%20time%2Carrived%20in%20time&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carrived%20just%20on%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carrived%20just%20in%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carrived%20on%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carrived%20in%20time%3B%2Cc0) is interesting...

[image]

As you can see, there's nothing particularly unusual about *[he arrived] **on** time* (there's one of those for every two instances of *[he arrived] **in** time*), but if we include ***just***, we find the ***in*** version is over a hundred times more common than ***on***.

That huge difference in prevalence means most native speakers will at least *notice* OP's relatively uncommon version, but it's not easy to explain *why* we don't normally use it.

I *think* it's because *to be **on** time* usually implies *to arrive at the time you are expected* (to be ***punctual***, neither early nor late), whereas *to be **in** time* usually implies *to [narrowly] avoid being late.*

Because of that, I think in *to arrive **just** on time* the adverb might tend to be interpreted as meaning ***exactly*** (arrive at **precisely** the expected time, be **very** punctual). Since that clashes with the ***in*** version, where ***just*** = almost not, barely, we tend to avoid it.